# Unity3d - Update function stops when MQTT message is received?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mqtt

I'm trying to build a simple MQTT application. I want to display the received MQTT message in a 3dText with Unity.

I put the string assignment into the Update() function, but appearently when a message is received the Update() function is stopped. When i click somewhere in the editor the Update() function wake up and update the string.

C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Utility;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions;

using System;

public class mqttTest : MonoBehaviour {
    private MqttClient client;
    public TextMesh mytext=null;
    string msg;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // create client instance 
        client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.83.128"),1883 , false , null ); 

        // register to message received 
        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived; 

        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
        client.Connect(clientId); 


        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "test" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE }); 


    }

    void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e) 
    { 
        msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        Debug.Log("Received: " + msg  );

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log("update");

        mytext.text = msg;

    }
}
```

This stopping is due to the development environment or the event mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because Unity only executes the PlayMode (`Update` events etc) while the UnityEditor window and in specific the `Game view` is focused. If another window has or gains focus in the moment your message is received Unity freezes until the `Game view` of unity editor gains focus again.

---

You can fix this by going to the [Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html) → [`Resolution and Presentation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html#Resolution) → `Resolution` and **enable** the option

> **Run In Background**
>    Enable this option to make the game keep running (rather than pausing) if the app loses focus.

Apparently this also applies to the player within UnityEditor itself.

**However it only works/exists if your project target is set to Standalone or Web.**

---

For iOS and Android this does not work because on those devices an app can not run in background. Unity automatically also applies the same behaviour to the player within UnityEditor itself.

But you can still get around it setting [`Application.runInBackground`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html) (which is basically what before mentioned option does)

> Should the player be running when the application is in the background?
>
> Default is `false` (application pauses when it is in the background).

directly from a component (attached to any Scene GameObject) like

```
public class EditorRunInBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake () 
    {
        if (Application.isEditor) Application.runInBackground = true;
    }
}
```

which only sets the `runInBackground` for the UnityEditor itself.

Alternatively if you don't want to attach it to anything you could also use a script with [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html)

```
public static class EditorRunInBackground
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void OnRuntimeMethodLoad()
    {
        if(Application.isEditor) Application.runInBackground = true;
    }
}
```

and could even play it within an `Editor` folder so it gets stripped of in a build.